Which schools of thought dealt with 'living in accord with nature'?
A few months ago I picked up a title on Stoicism, and it surprised me that the centerpiece of the philosophy seemed to be living in accord with nature in order to achieve eudaimonia (good spirit, flourishing).
I'm also a student of Buddhism, and while this isn't the explicit aim of Buddhism, much of it's wisdom seems to fulfill the goal of living in accord with nature.
My question is: which other philosophies or thinkers focused on this idea, living in accord with nature?

Certainly a lot of contemporary environmentalist, ecological, or indigenous/postcolonial philosophy deals w/ questions of nature, what it means to live 'in accord' with it, etc. "deep ecology" or "ecosophy", for instance, are a few 1900s terms that get used

If you broaden the question to "living in accord with human nature" (I feel like it's fair to say Stoicism is more concerned with human nature than environment-nature), I think a lot of branches of philosophy will lay claim to "the natural order"--enlightenment philosophers made a big deal about the state of nature and natural law, so e.g. Hobbes, Locke, Hume, Marx, etc all make some argument about what is 'natural' for humans before laws or society complicate matters.

Stoicism

@Cdn_Dev "Living in accord with nature" is a quite general principle which has been interpreted in different directions. E.g., see HenryThoreau en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_David_Thoreau

The "nature" Stoics had in mind is not what one might think from the phrase. They took the idea from Aristotle, see SEP, Moral Character:"The Stoics assume that the good life for human beings is a life in accord with nature. They agree with Aristotle that the human being’s essence is a life in accord with reason. So to find what accords with nature, they look to the development of the human being’s rational powers." Not exactly congenial to Buddhism. Please clarify what sort of "nature" to live in accord with you are looking for.

nature - the material world and its phenomena
